# CP1251 Encoding issue in html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, html2pdf, cp1251

I was download and setup script from:http://www.html2pdf.fr/en
It works fine with default encoding, but when I try to generate docs with characters in CP-1251, I got white spaces instead of characters. 
Also All my files in CP-1251,data in base in CP-1251 and as you can see I use simple font -Arial

Please, maybe exist some solution to get it to work.

P/s sorry for my english

```
    ob_start();

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/res/exemple00.php');

$content = ob_get_clean();

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../html2pdf.class.php');

try

{

    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');

    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');

    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

    $content1=$html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
```

// Some php code

```
    $db->query("set names cp1251");

$query="SELECT data from files Where id=$file_id ";

$result=$db->query($query);

    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();

$content=($row['data']);
```

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

header("Content-Length: ".strlen(content));

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Invoice#'.$invoice_id.'.pdf');

print $content;

```
}

catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) { echo $e; }    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not using this library, but are you setting your encoding in the HTML2PDF constructor?

```
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr', true, 'CP-1251');
```

If it does not work, try 'cp1251' or 'CP1251', I do not find list of recognized encodings in the documentation. You can also use iconv and convert to UTF-8 as it seems to be a default.

Comment: I get the next:

`html_entity_decode() [function.html-entity-decode]: charset CP-1251' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1 in /var/www/myproject/parsingHTML.class.php on line 203`


When I try "CP1251" or "cp1251" and etc. - it is again white spaces instead characters.
Also, I was try use UTF-8 encoding and iconv function, in this case i get message from Acrobat Reader "PDF document is damaged".

Any way thank you for answer.